# Qt - Send Signal To Specific Objects Based On Content Of Signal

Tags: qt

I have a structure that I want 1 class to emit to multiple different classes via a slot. However, not all classes should *always* get the message. There is a field in the structure called "ID", and based on the ID, only certain objects should receive the structure (ones that match the ID).

Currently, I have the emitting class and receiving classes derive from QObjects. I then make the emitting class the parent of the receiving classes, and then have the parent peek into the structure ID field, look up the children by ID, and then send the structure to them via method, ie child->pushData(struct).

Is there a better way to do this? Can I selectively send signals based on the content of the signal?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

This is another way:

```
class ClassReceiving_TypeInQuestion
{
  Q_OBJECT:
  protected:
    explicit ClassReceiving_TypeInQuestion( int idOfType );//....

  public slots:
    void onRxStructSlot( const TypeInQuestion& );

  private:
    //Only called when ID matches....
    virtual void onRxStruct( const TypeInQuestion& ) = 0;
    int idOfType_;    
};

//.cpp
void ClassReceivingStruct::onRxStructSlot( const TypeInQuestion& value )
{
  if( value.id_ == idOfType_ )
  {
    onRxStruct( value );//Could be signal also...
  }
}
```

Any of the classes wanting to receive the signal inherits from ClassReceivingStruct, or alternatively:

```
struct ClassEmitting_TypeInQuestion;

class ClassReceiving_TypeInQuestion
{
  Q_OBJECT:
  public:
    explicit ClassReceiving_TypeInQuestion( 
      ClassEmitting_TypeInQuestion& sender, 
      int idOfType )
    : idOfType
     {
       connect( &sender, SIGNAL(onTxStruct(TypeInQuestion)), 
                this, SLOT(onRxStruct(TypeInQuestion)) ); 
     }
  signals:
    void onTxStruct( const TypeInQuestion& );

  private slots:
    void onRxStruct( const TypeInQuestion& );

  private:
    int idOfType_;    
};

//.cpp
void ClassReceivingStruct::onRxStruct( const TypeInQuestion& value )
{
  if( value.id_ == idOfType_ )
  {
    emit onTxStruct( value );//Could be signal also...
  }
}

class Client
{
  Q_OBJECT

  public:
       enum{ eID = 0 };
      Client( ClassEmitting_TypeInQuestion& sender )
      : receiver_( sender, eID )
      {
         //connect to receiver_....
      }
  private slots:

  private:          
    ClassReceiving_TypeInQuestion receiver_;
};
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. So if I understand, you are delegating checking the structure ID to the receiving class? Doesn't this mean that all receivers will get the structure, and then check to see if they should discard it? Won't that be inefficient, especially if the structure is large?

Comment: Also, I see you're using references in your signal/slots. Is this safe? Can the emitted reference goes out of scope by the time it reaches other slots?

Comment: @trianta2, if signals use const references, they are still passed by value. Thus it is pretty safe to do so.

Comment: @trianta2, The fact that I use const reference ensures that multiple copies aren't made. You have to make sure that your slot objects have the same thread associated with it than the sender (direct connection, not queued.